# How to use \cite correctly? - \cite results in "?"

Tags: citing, harvard-style

This is my `main.tex`:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=full]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    % Paper layout
    \usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    % use links for table of contents, citations, ...
    \usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = black]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{harvard}
    \let\harvardleftorig\harvardleft
    \newcommand\citevgl
      {\def\harvardleft{(vgl.\ \global\let\harvardleft\harvardleftorig}%
       \cite
      }
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

    \begin{document}
    \chapter[some title]{some title}
some text \citevgl{NT}
      \renewcommand{\thepage}{}
      \listoffigures
      \bibliography{literatur}
      \bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \end{document}
```

This is my `literatur.bib`:

```
@Article{NT,
title = {Management-Team},
year = {Abgerufen am 22 Juni 2018},
url = {https://www.exapmle.com}
}
```

[image: and my problem]

My question is: how I have to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you run LaTeX/BibTeX/LaTeX/LaTeX?

Comment: Normally the problem is just that you forgot to run BibTeX: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). But it could also be a more specific reason. You may want to check out the `.log` *and* `.blg` files for errors and warnings.

Comment: In configure Texmaker I selected the PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View Pdf @JosephWright

Comment: what setup are you using? also, could you turn your example into a full MWE. I don't have the files, you're including.

Comment: The `.blg` message suggests that a file called `literatur.bib` was found (that is good), but that it does not contain the entries listed there. In particular `NT` can't be found. Do you have several files called `literatur.bib`? Maybe BibTeX finds the wrong file. Try renaming the file to something more descriptive and try again.

Comment: there is only one file that named literatur.bib @moewe

Comment: @moewe yes it contains NT

Comment: You've not show us the full source (including the citations) or the `.bib` file: as others have said, it looks like one or other is wrong.

Comment: @moewe Now I am getting this error when I am trying to mwe:
`i couldn't open database file literatur.bib ---line 25 of file main.aux: \bibdata{literatur: } I am skipping whatever remains of this command`

Comment: Did you write `\bibliography{literatur:}` instead of `\bibliography{literatur}`?

Comment: The `harvard` cite package is not compatible `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`.

Comment: @moewe was that the problem all the time :D What should I use for bibstyle?

Comment: If you insist on using the `harvard` package use one of its styles: `agsm`, `dcu`, `kluwer`: https://ctan.org/pkg/harvard. Or just don't use `harvard`.

Comment: Normally you should not need `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` it can do more harm than good in some situations. Just use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` that should be enough for most intents and purposes (especially in German texts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `harvard`, you also have to specify a compatible bibliography style. Here I use `agsm` which seems to be the most generic one.

Also, `@article` is not the right type for the item and `@misc` seems better; as Harvard styles need an author, you should either specify `author` or, like here, `key` (choose a meaningful name rather than `SOMETHING`).

In the code I use `filecontents*` just not to clobber my files; you can employ your `.bib` file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{NT,
key = {SOMETHING},
title = {Management-Team},
year = {Abgerufen am 22 Juni 2018},
url = {https://www.example.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=full]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Paper layout
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% use links for table of contents, citations, ...
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = black, citecolor = black, filecolor = black, urlcolor = black]{hyperref}

\let\harvardleftorig\harvardleft
\newcommand\citevgl
  {\def\harvardleft{(vgl.\ \global\let\harvardleft\harvardleftorig}%
   \cite
  }
% packages and theorems go here
%\input{packages}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\citationstyle{abbr}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einführung}
some text \citevgl{NT}

%\listoffigures
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

A couple of points:

1. `hyperref` should go last even after your `packages` (only a few packages must be loaded after it)
2. `\include{packages}` is wrong, use `\input` (but be careful about the previous warning)
3. `utf8x` is largely obsolete and unmaintained; prefer `utf8` (by the way, with recent versions of LaTeX, after 2018-04-01, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is not even needed)

[image]